# Calculate growth percentage using sql on multiple stocks

Tags: sql, postgresql, stock

I would like to calculate the growth for one ticker, while I'm querying multiple tickers. The code I'm trying only works when I run it on a single ticker.

Source Table:

| line | ticker | calendardate | revenueusd | growth |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | INTC | 2021-09-30 | 19192 |  |
| 2 | AMD | 2021-09-30 | 4313 |  |
| 3 | AMD | 2021-12-31 | 4826 | ? |
| 4 | INTC | 2021-12-31 | 20528 | ? |
| 5 | INTC | 2022-03-31 | 18353 | ? |
| 6 | AMD | 2022-03-31 | 5887 | ? |
| 7 | INTC | 2022-06-30 | 15321 | ? |
| 8 | AMD | 2022-06-30 | 6550 | ? |

```
SELECT 
ticker,
calendardate,
(revenueusd - LAG (revenueusd) OVER (ORDER BY calendardate ASC)) / LAG (revenueusd) OVER (ORDER BY calendardate ASC) AS growth
FROM
    sf1
WHERE
    ticker IN ('AMD', 'INTC')
ORDER BY calendardate ASC
```

Is there anything that I can add to make **LAG** get the corresponding ticker not just the one "above"? Currently this code at line 4 (INTC) would use the revenue for line 3 (AMD). Insted I would need line 1 (INTC) data.

The data comes from: [Nasdaq, Core US Fundamentals Data](https://data.nasdaq.com/databases/SF1/data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to `PARTITION BY` and what you also need to avoid integer division is to9 convert the data into decimal or float

```
SELECT 
ticker,
calendardate,
  (revenueusd - LAG (revenueusd) OVER (PARTITION BY ticker ORDER BY calendardate ASC)::DECIMAL(7,2)
  / LAG (revenueusd) OVER (PARTITION BY ticker ORDER BY calendardate ASC))::DECIMAL (7,2) AS growth
FROM
    sf1
WHERE
    ticker IN ('AMD', 'INTC')
ORDER BY calendardate ASC
```

| ticker | calendardate | growth |
| --- | --- | --- |
| AMD | 2021-09-30 | *null* |
| INTC | 2021-09-30 | *null* |
| INTC | 2021-12-31 | 20527.00 |
| AMD | 2021-12-31 | 4825.00 |
| AMD | 2022-03-31 | 5886.00 |
| INTC | 2022-03-31 | 18352.00 |
| AMD | 2022-06-30 | 6549.00 |
| INTC | 2022-06-30 | 15320.00 |

> ```
> SELECT 8
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/5N4pDxIg)

Comment: Works beautifully! Thanks!